# How to make a NSTimer call from user app login time to 24 hours using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nstimer

My Problem :

I am using `JSON` parser via parse some datas and showing into my app. The parser data Once user `logged` into `app`, then `JSON` login url generating one ID. Help of this ID only I am getting further data's for my application. Now the problem is the ID valid upto `24 hours` (if continuously user logged In). After 24 hours we cant get any data's by refreshing anything.( It's like login session time out from backend). So for that I need to Indimate users for every 24 hours (Need to relogin or else generate new ID otherwise I cant get updated data).

1. Now I am storing time and date into plist once user logged into my
   application.
2. In appdelegate I want to make a timer call from user login time to
   24 hours.

I hope above details giving you clearance about my problem.

Comment: This is an exact copy of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431177/how-to-make-a-timer-call-from-user-app-login-time-to-24-hours-using-objective-c). Don't repost the same bad question under a different account. Fix the question to be acceptable.

Comment: plz help me. I need solution for above question!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a timer. So as the time storing.
You need to add a error handler for your http requests and see if the server returns a token expiration error - then perform a relogin action. Usually it's a `403` status code.

You cannot and shouldn't rely on timer because:

1. App lifetime may be shorter. If your app does not provide VoIP functions, it won't perform any code during background state. User may decide to force quit your app and you cannot do anything.
2. A server may change the token lifetime

Comment: Yes. The server changing the tokens life time. Thats what I need to give alert Once user reached 24th hours. Plz post some code for that

Comment: You didn't show your code. The code depends on how you perform your requests. Read the manuals on response handling, check the headers of error response and then write an error handler for this case.